# how to compute power in efficient way

Tags: c, function

Given a function such that f(N)=1^1*2^2*3^3.....N^N. I have to calculate f(N)/f(r)*f(N-r).
My c code is given below but it works for small N such as 5 or 6.

```
#include<stdio.h>

unsigned long long power(long x, long y)
{
    unsigned long long temp;
    if( y == 0)
        return 1;
    temp = power(x, y/2);
    if (y%2 == 0)
        return temp*temp;
    else
        return x*temp*temp;
}

int main(){
    unsigned long long N,M,Q,r[100001],j;
    int t,i;
    scanf("%d",&t);
    while(t--){
        scanf("%llu%llu%llu",&N,&M,&Q);
        for(i=0;i<Q;i++)
            scanf("%llu",&r[i]);
        for(i=0;i<Q;i++){
         unsigned long long mult=1;
           for(j=2;j<=N;j++){
              mult=mult*(power(j,j));
        }
           unsigned long long mult1=mult;
            mult=1;
          //unsigned long long ans=mult/((power(r[i],r[i]))*(power((N-r[i]),(N-r[i]))));
            for(j=2;j<=r[i];j++)
                mult=mult*(power(j,j));
            unsigned long long mult2=mult;
            mult=1;
            for(j=2;j<=N-r[i];j++)
                mult=mult*(power(j,j));
            unsigned long long mult3=mult;
           mult=1;
            unsigned long long ans=mult1/(mult2*mult3);
            printf("%llu\n",ans%M);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

suppose, f(5)=1^1*2^2*3^3*4^4*5^5=86400000.if N is very  large N<=10^5.then how can i store such a big value.can any one give me an efficient algorithm to find that value and store it in any array.thanks in advance.

Comment: If you use long long types you have the range of –9,223,372,036,854,775,808 to 9,223,372,036,854,775,807.  If you use floats, you get from 3.4E +/- 38 (7 digits).  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s3f49ktz.aspx

Comment: As an example consider N=100000 and r=1. Then you have `f(100000)/(f(1)*f(99999))` which is `100000^100000`. In other words, the answer has 500,000 digits. From which it follows that you need to find or write a BigInteger library.

Comment: Can you not do a bit of algebra on the equation?

Comment: @user267144 you should first remove common factors from the fraction

Comment: your function grows quicker than fact(N) so i think you won't be able to use it with N = 10^5 in the range of a long long.

Answer (score 1):

For unsigned integer exponents, it's mostly just shorthand for repeated multiplication (e.g. `x^9` is `x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x`).

To compute it efficiently (reduce the number of multiplications), you can use temporary calculations. For example, for `x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x` you can calculate `y = x*x` and do `y*y*y*y*x` instead; and this is 5 multiplications instead of 8. You could also do `y = x*x` then `z = y*y` then `z*z*x` to get it down to 4 multiplications.

It turns out that binary is awesome and makes it extremely easy to find the least number of multiplications needed - the binary digits of the exponent tell you.

More specifically, (for unsigned integer exponents, ignoring overflows) this works:

```
    result = 1;
    temp = x;
    while( exponent != 0) {
        if( (exponent & 1) != 0) {
            result *= temp;
        }
        exponent >>= 1;
        temp *= temp;
    }
    return result;
```

Of course overflows will be a problem. For large numbers you will need some sort of "big integer" code that can be used for the multiplications (where both the `temp` and `result` variables are "big integers").

A "big integer" is typically just a (variable length) array of integers, where each element of the array represents one digit of the number in a large base (e.g. "base 4294967296" for 32-bit digits). I'm sure you can find the algorithms for multiplication and division if you want to implement it yourself; or a suitable C library if you don't.

The other alternative is to use floating point. I wouldn't recommend this for anything more than approximations because you will get precision loss when working on large numbers (and you will still have overflows for "very large numbers").

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
unsigned long long power(long x, long y)
{
    if( 0 == y ) return 1;
    if( 1 == y ) return x;

    unsigned long long result = x;
    for(long i = 2; i < y; i++ )
    {
        result *= x;
    }
    return( result );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have the fast exponential function:

```
unsigned long long fastpow(unsigned long long a, int b)
{
    unsigned long long res = 1;
    while (b) {
        if (b & 1) res *= a;
        b >>= 1;
        a *= a;
    }
    return res;
}
```

it's used normally in cryptography environments, but can be used here.

As I have said in the comments, the function you are trying to write grows quicker than fact(N), so you will not be able to calculate it for the range you put in your question (10^5) as you'll get numbers large enough to don't them fit easily anywhere.

With a unsigned long long result, you can only get to:

```
f(0) -> 1
f(1) -> 1
f(2) -> 4
f(3) -> 108
f(4) -> 27648
f(5) -> 86400000
f(6) -> 4031078400000
f(7) -> 3319766398771200000
f(8) -> overflows in 64 bit.
```